# MySQL join same column name

Tags: mysql, join

Right now I have this code:

```
SELECT * FROM orders, products WHERE product_id=products.id AND `geleverd` = 0
```

Wich returns as this:
[image]

I also have this code for a button:

```
echo "<a onclick='return window.confirm(\"Weet je zeker dat  ".$row['merk']." ".$row['model']." geleverd is?\")' href='change_order_status.php?id=". $row['id'] ."' title='Delete Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok' style='color:black'></span></a>";
```

But for some reason id returns a 9 instead of a 1

This is the output of a print of $row

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [id] => 9
    [1] => 2019-1
    [ordernummer] => 2019-1
    [2] => 9
    [product_id] => 9
    [3] => 2
    [aantal] => 2
    [4] => aaa
    [omschrijving] => aaa
    [5] => 0
    [geleverd] => 0
    [6] => 9
    [7] => Samsung
    [merk] => Samsung
    [8] => Tablet S2
    [model] => Tablet S2
    [9] => 1
    [threshold] => 1
)
```

and:

```
(
    [0] => 3
    [id] => 9
    [1] => 789
    [ordernummer] => 789
    [2] => 9
    [product_id] => 9
    [3] => 10
    [aantal] => 10
    [4] => test
    [omschrijving] => test
    [5] => 0
    [geleverd] => 0
    [6] => 9
    [7] => Samsung
    [merk] => Samsung
    [8] => Tablet S2
    [model] => Tablet S2
    [9] => 1
    [threshold] => 1
)
```

How can I fix that Id will be 1 for the first row and not 9 and for the second row id will be 3 instead of 9

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Alias` for the tables, and combine/rename the columns that you need.

```
SELECT o.id as orderId, p.id as productId, -all the columns you need with the alias first- FROM orders as o, products as p WHERE o.product_id=p.id AND `geleverd` = 0
```